# I love maths, but my school is limited in its teachings.

Tags: soft-question, advice, learning

I'm not sure how well this question will be received but, I feel there is no harm in asking. I'm 17 soon to be 18. I was in my applied maths course, but not anymore, not due to difficulty, but I can be quite impertinent at times and sometimes get over excited in class. but that isn't the point, my question is, where is a good place for me to start learning maths? I have recently started looking at matrix determinant and its really interesting, however, I'm not sure where to go now. I really enjoy maths, however, I've only been studying it for 2 years due to circumstances, so I am still naive in regards to how much I can actually do by myself. I'm sorry if I come across a certain way, I don't mean to seem rude or arrogant, I just kind of fell in love with maths the moment I saw it, and I've wanted to pursue it since, but I don't fit into school very well, and the curriculum is limited at the school I attend.

I appreciate any answer at all, so thank you very much anyone who toke the time to read this.

Comment: It'll be more helpful if we have additional information. For example, are you in high school or college? What's your major or intended major? What you've already know?

Comment: Did you have a look at the related questions (on the right hand side)? The problem I see is that books can bring you up to speed on many aspects, but at some point you will probably need interaction with a real person so that you can understand things which are a bit tricky much quicker. Self-learning can be difficult at times.

Comment: You say you "fell in love with maths the moment i saw it," but it's not very clear what that's supposed to mean. Can you give us a better idea of what you saw that you fell in love with?

Comment: Then Welcome to Math Stack Exchange!

Comment: i apologize for the vagueness in the question i posed. I go to high school/secondary school in ireland, and usually its a 6 year/5 year program, depending if you want to sit the extra year. i didnt finish first year or attend second year. The school i attended didnt have a great maths/english/history teacher as it was the same person, so it was kind of limited. but, in my third year, we were brought into it with graphing functions, and since then, he didnt teach much else. but after the next year, we got a proper teacher for applied maths. and then the subject captivated me, more than others.

Comment: i apologize, im not to apt with describing my feelings towards things, so i apologize for any frustration i cause. i was just curious as to what i could do to educate myself.

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful (and you should delete the comments and edit that information into your main question). However, I'm still a little confused. Where I'm from, "applied math" refers to some of the most contrived and lifeless parts of the curriculum: interest calculations, profit calculations, basic arithmetic. What did you see that interested you?

Comment: Hello Paudie. What to recommend depends partly on your present level of proficiency in algebra. If it is average, you could learn more on your own using *E-Z Algebra* and *E-Z Trigonometry* by Douglas Downing. If it is (or becomes) above average, I would recommend Gelfand's books *The Method of Coordinates*, *Algebra*, *Functions and Graphs* and *Trigonometry*. (Of course, you can try these anyway.) Also for very bright high schoolers there are the books listed here: http://www.maa.org/publications/ebooks/anneli-lax-new-mathematical-library Both books by Niven are excellent.

Comment: “I don't fit into school very well” ... I have some online mathematics exercises / tutorials (autocorrected), ranging from kindergarten to college, at: http://www.public-domain-materials.com/folder-student-exercise-tasks-for-mathematics-language-arts-etc---autocorrected.html ... Also, the material is public-domain. You can copy the entire website if you like and alter it to fit your own purposes.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, depends on your current level, you can consider

1) High school textbook in your country(if there is a standard curriculum or similar), if you are not familiar with it already.

2) If you're OK with high school level stuff, consider self-studying introductory level calculus/linear-algebra at college level. The textbook/curriculum of it should not heavily depend on country and location. Pick any textbook you like.

3) If you want to be a math major in college, consider studying a little bit real analysis/abstract algebra, although it might be too challenge for you now.